# How to send data from child process to server, using poll() in c?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, polling

```
    struct pollfd fds[hts];

    for(i=0;i<hts;i++){
        fds[i].fd=fdh[i][0];    
        fds[i].events = POLLIN;

    }
    int h=poll(fds,hts,0);
    for (i = 0; i < hts; i++)
        if(fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
            read(fdh[i][0], &Mess, sizeof(Mess));}
```

it's my code on the server and i'm trying send message from the child process.

```
write(1,&Mess, sizeof(Mess));
```

i try something like this on child process but revents never been activated.

what'd i do for send message from data or where is my fault.

thanks!

Comment: And standard output (`STDOUT_FILENO`, file descriptor `1`) of the child is the write-end of one of the pipes? And you do call `poll` in a loop? And why do you use a zero timeout? Lastly, do you check what `poll` really returns?

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive (and [others](http://idownvotedbecau.se/)).